# d3 react chart width calculation

Tags: d3.js, reactjs

I have a simple d3 barChart inside a React Component using react-faux-dom.

In order to create the graph

```
    let svg = d3.select(ReactFauxDOM.createElement('div')).append('svg')
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
```

and to go back to react:

```
    let graph = svg.node().toReact();
```

This is working great and allows me to fastly create d3 graphs. I can manage width by passing it as a prop from parent component.

Does anybody know any more elegant way to do it?
I would like to select an element, and read the .offsetWidth proprierty.

But, of course, when I do:

```
    svg.offsetWidth
```

I get undefined...

any ideas?

Comment: I've had luck with `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).offsetWidth`

Comment: I think it is a solution.
I still try to find a more elegant way!

But this could work well for all inline styles in general

Comment: You can also try measuring the element after it has mounted, storing that in the state and then re-rendering using that new information.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit older, but since I was looking for a solution to this last week and could not find an answer I liked, I figured I would post it.

I did not like including `ReactDOM` in each of my components just to measure, and I also have a requirement for updating on width changes. For those reasons I ended up with a solution similar to what Olical mentioned, and also incorporate `react-resize-detector`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Resize from 'react-resize-detector';

class D3Chart extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      width: 500,
      height: 250
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handelResize(this.refs.wrapper.offsetWidth)
  }

  handelResize(width = 500, height = 250) {
    this.setState({width: width, height: height});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref="wrapper" height={this.state.height}>
        <Resize handleWidth onResize={this.handelResize.bind(this)}/>
        <svg ref="svg" width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height}></svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default D3Chart;
```